# how to transverse arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to know how to transverse my average function into this result function if u are getting ?

This is the main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  ArrayList < Calculations > students = new ArrayList < Calculations > ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   Calculations s = new Calculations();
   System.out.print("Enter name : ");
   s.name = scan.next();
   System.out.print("Eter percentage : ");
   s.percetage = scan.nextDouble();
   students.add(s);
   System.out.println("Enter Mrks Obtained");

  }


  for (Calculations s: students) {
   s.result();
   for (Calculations i: students) {
    s.Average();
   }


  }
 }

}
```

This is result class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculations {



 public String name;
 public double percetage;
 public int integer;
 public void result() {
  System.out.println((percetage >= 35.0 f ? (name + " Pass") : (name + " Fail")));

 }
 public void Average() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int mark[] = new int[5];
  int i;
  float sum = 0;
  float avg, perc;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter marks Obtained in 5 Subjects : ");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   mark[i] = scan.nextInt();
   sum = sum + mark[i];
  }

  avg = sum / 5;
  perc = (sum / 500) * 100;

  System.out.print("Average Marks = " + avg);

  System.out.print("\nPercentage = " + perc + "%");
 }


}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are you trying to achieve, and where is this code snippet failing?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Calculations s : students){
        s.result();
        //for(Calculations i : students){s.Average();  }
        s.Average();
}
```

you dont have to loop your arraylist twice. try changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It was so hard to follow through your incomplete question, which is not specific either. Your program works fine in my eclipse. I would suggest following:

1) Check the name of the fields/ spelling in you Calculations class to match exactly as it's been used in the main class.
2) Since you're inputting String Scanner, try to read lines as follows:

```
s.name = scan.nextLine();
```

I hope it helped.